# Replacing Sequential foreach with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

In the following `foreach p : allPersons`, it's clear (since the logic is sequential) that the map/Dictionary can be used for caching/memoization.

```
Dictionary<string, int> personNameToIdMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(p : allPersons)
{

 int outputId;

 if(personNameToIdMap.TryGetValue(p.Name, out outputId))
 {
   // nothing to do since map contained the p.Name
 }
 else
 { 
    outputId = doExpensiveLookup(p.Name);
    personNameToIdMap[p.Name] = outputId;
 }

  ...

  p.Id = outputId;

}
```

If I replace the above `foreach` with `Parallel.ForEach`, will each thread share `personNameToIdMap`?

Comment: Note that the foreach syntax you showed isn't C# ;)  Interesting mix of C# and C++11 syntax here...

Comment: Reed - I recently worked in Java for a fair amount of time, so my C# syntax is not 100% - ha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in case of `Parallel.Foreach` each thread will be using same instance of `Dictionary`.

If you really want parallelism you can use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which is thread safe version of `Dictionary`

Comment: +1 ConcurrentDictionary is definitely the way to go, but the logic would likely be best if changed slightly.

Comment: +1.  With a Concurrent Dictionary, do you expect there to be much contention in a `Parallel.ForEach` where the threads end up fighting over one another?

Comment: @Moo-Juice obviously there will be a slight overhead because of multiple threads, that's why I wrote `if you really want parallelism` :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice in this case, the contention should be very low, as reads are very cheap, there are few writes/adds (in this code), and CD does very fine-grained locking.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, got you.  I suppose if it allows multiple readers, this could be quite performant due to the `doExpensiveLookup` part.

Comment: If I don't use the `ConcurrentDictionary`, then each iteration in the `foreach` loop will be sequential? In other words, if I don't use the CD, then the `Parallel.ForEach` effectively is a regular, sequential `foreach`?

Comment: @Kevin no, if you will use normal Dictionary inside Paralle.Foreach you may end up in incorrect results because multiple threads will be trying to change same object at a time

Comment: Since (as I understand) adding to a Dictionary is not atomic, then it'd be possible, while a thread is writing to the Dictionary for results of `doExpensiveOperation("Kevin")`, for another thread to pre-empt it. As a result, the benefit of caching `doExpensiveOperation("Kevin")` would be lost?

Comment: @Kevin It's worse than that - `Dictionary<T,U>` is not thread safe, so you get undefined behavior if you're using it from multiple threads without locking/synchronization.  Basically, you really can't know what you'll get - it may be the right answer, multiple threads may both try to write to each  other, you may get a crash trying to access some internal structure before it's setup, etc...

Answer (score 2):

[Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064835/65358) is completely correct - `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` would be the proper approach.  Given that, you'll likely want to change your method slightly to take advantage of `ConcurrentDictionary`'s [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> personNameToIdMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

Parallel.ForEach(allPersons, p =>
{
    int outputId = personNameToIdMap.GetOrAdd(p.Name, name => doExpensiveLookup(p.Name));

    // ...
    p.Id = outputId;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make sure that `allPersons` is thread-safe? Currently it's a `List<Person>`, but I read on C# List documentation that `List` is not thread-safe

Comment: @Kevin No - `IEnumerable<T>` is inherently not thread safe - As such, `Parallel` will take care of that part for you.  Using a `List<T>` is fine there.